# Best way to keep inserting large volume of data via JDBC. Batch insert or stored procedure?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, spring, jdbc

I'm using `Spring` connecting to `Sql Server 2008 R2` via `JDBC`.

All I need is to insert a large amount of data to a table in the database as fast as possible. I'm wondering which way is better:

1. Use `Spring` batch insert mention [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-advanced-jdbc)
2. Create stored procedure in database and call it on Java side

Which one is better?

Comment: You might have a better chance receiving a more thorough answer over at [dba.SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on two things stored producer would take up the database time where as batch would take up time on the program side. so depending on what you are more concerned with it is really up to up. Me i would prefer the batch as to keep the database time free reducing errors that might occur. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Spring batch is an excellent framework and it can be used as an ETL (Extract, Transform, Load) tool  with respect to database.

Spring batch divides any import job in 3 steps:
1. Read : Read data from any source. It can be any other database, any file (XML, CSV or any other) or anything else
2. Process: Process input data, validate it and may convert it to your required objects.
3. Save: Save data into database or any custom file format

Spring batch is useful when you need long running jobs with restart/resume capabilities.
Also it is lot slower that any direct DB import tool like impdp for Oracle. Spring batch saves its state in database so it is an overhead and consumes long time. However you can hack spring batch and make it not save the state in DB but it costs loss of restart/resume capabilities.

So if speed is your prime requirement, you should choose some database specific option.
But if you need do some validation and/or processing Spring batch is an excellent option, you just need to configure it properly. Also Spring batch provides scalability and database independence.

Comment: Sorry but I'm talking about Spring-JDBC instead of Spring Batch